# Pass 128 bits from managed C++ to C#

Tags: c#, managed-c++

I have a function in a managed C++ DLL that needs to pass 128 bits back to C#.  I have found quite a bit on the subject calling *unmanaged* C++ from C# but not so much about managed to managed calls.

This call will happen in a tight loop, potentially billions of times a day across a server farm.

What's the most efficient way to pass back the bits?

So far I considered using a GUID structure as a convenient container for the bits, but it's not clear to me whether or not the .NET runtime will GC that structure, and I'm not sure if that's the most efficient mechanism.

Comment: "billions of times" per day isn't a tight loop. Billions of times per minute *might* be worth spending time optimizing, and billions of times per second would be pretty good throughput, but per day doesn't sound like anything to worry too much about. Anyway, if performance matters, make sure to measure, measure, measure. Don't just trust whatever people here or elsewhere suggest. Measure each candidate implementation, and pick the best one

Comment: Isn't it possible to send simply array of bits or to send array of four integers?
I'm sure that managed-to-managed transmission will be correctly maintained by GC

Comment: If on 64bit, just use 2 `Int64` parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, passing around variables of the following type defined in C++/CLI:

```
public value struct Int128
{
    System::Int64 lo;
    System::Int64 hi;
};
```

should be about the fastest you can do.

Comment: How do I return this struct to C#?  I get a compile error in C++: `__declspec(dllexport) cannot be applied to a function with the __clrcall calling convention`

Comment: @Eric J.: You are not doing managed C++ then. You must do "unmanaged " C++ if you are writing a DLL whose functions you export with dllexport. This is what the compiler tells you.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with VC++ (though I am familiar with C++ in general).  I'm compiling with `/clr`.  What else do I need to do in order to create a managed DLL in C++?

Comment: @Eric J.: http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/index.htm or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/cppcliintro01.aspx . Basically, you write .NET code in C++, pretty much the same way you would in C#, but you can access normal C++ code. To use this class, you'd have to write something like `public ref struct Utils { static void UseInt128(Int128 i) { ... } };`